# If two monic polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ (p-adic integer coefficient) are relatively prime modulo p, then do they generate $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, p-adic-numbers

I'm currently reading a paper of Rene Schoof, and I got stuck in a line. And I'm trying to check the above sentence.
Although that seems to be elementary, I hope someone can give me a counterexample or a proof.

Thank you.

Comment: Polynomial Bezout identity?

Comment: Your $\mathbf Z_p$ is presumably notation for the integers mod $p$, not the $p$-adic integers. In a PID, if two elements are relatively prime do you know if they generate the ring?

Comment: I'm Sorry for the notation, by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ I mean the ring of p-adic integers. By modulo p, I mean modulo $p\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$.

Answer (score 10):

If the two polynomials are $f,g$, then the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-module $M := \mathbb{Z}_{p}[X]/(f,g)$ is finitely generated (since at least one of $f,g$ is monic) and satisfies $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}} \mathbb{Z}_{p}/(p) = 0$, hence $M = 0$ by Nakayama.